# android: onProgressUpdate(Asynctask) stops scrolling Scrollview

Tags: android, android-asynctask, scroll, scrollview

I have an Asynctask, which should add a Rowlayout by using onProgressUpdate, to a Tablelayout, which is inside a Scrollingview. During Asynctask is working, the rows are added to the tablelayout and everything is fine. But during the Asynctask is working i can't scroll the Scrollview although i see the added rows. I can only scroll if the Asynctask has finished.

Asynctask

```
  private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, String> 
  {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {        
        Integer k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if(i == 80)
            {
                System.out.println("Debug Breakpoint");
            }
            publishProgress("hey");
        }       
        return k.toString();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... ProduktListe)
    {
        writeSomeThing();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {             

    }   
  }
```

Create Row

```
  public void writeSomeThing() 
  {     
            //make here breakpoint
            MainActivity context = this;


            TableLayout searchBody = (TableLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            TableRow rowView = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.reintuding, null);

            searchBody.addView(rowView);    
  }
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/Gesamt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#0099cc" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"
            android:minHeight="610dp">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:stretchColumns="0" >

            </TableLayout>


        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

reintuding.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: My guess is that you are adding this rows too fast, so it's difficult to wedge with gestures into UI message queue. Try adding `Thread.sleep(1000)` inside `doInBackground` and see if it scrolls during AsyncTask execution.

Comment: With sleep, it works. But now it jurk when I scroll. I think this happens after the 1 second sleep. Because it jurks (= i can't scroll at the time), when it add an row.

Comment: It's just standart behavior, the thing is, when you are adding a view to your view hierarchy it executes in the UI thread and this operation is not so fact and so no more UI actions would procceed at that time. I would recommend you inflating all views somewhen at start and make a reference to `searchBody`, then it should perform better, because `findViewById` and `inflate` are heavy operations.